# Dataclass being invoked when import (?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I've defined this dataclass:

```
import logging
from config.config_parser import ConfigParser
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    id_execution: int
    flag: bool
    log: str = logging.getLogger('log_handler')
    con: str = ConfigParser.get_conf('A', 'a_value')
    name: str = None
    surname: str = None
```

This dataclass is being invoked in other 'traditional' class like:

```
from handlers.handler_a import A
from config.config_parser import ConfigParser

# Configuration initialization
ConfigParser.initialize_config()

# Instantiate A dataclass
a = A()
```

ConfigParser fails because it is not initalized. It seems like A is being intialized in the above import, before the configParser and everything.

How is this possible? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That error occurs when importing the class definition. `ConfigParser` needs to be defined where `A` is defined, not where `A` is imported/initialized.

Answer (score 1):

`ConfigParser.get_conf('A', 'a_value')` is being called during the creation of `A`, which is why it is failing.  In a normal class, this would be written

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.con = ConfigParser.get_conf('A', 'a_value')
```

and `get_conf` would only be called when an instance is created.

We can tell the dataclass to do the same thing by making that attribute a `field` with a `default_factory`:

import logging
from config.config_parser import ConfigParser
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

```
@dataclass
class A:
    id_execution: int
    flag: bool
    log: str = logging.getLogger('log_handler')
    con: str = field(default_factory=lambda: ConfigParser.get_conf('A', 'a_value'))
    name: str = None
    surname: str = None
```

Comment: Hello Patrick! This approach seems to works fine. What I cannot reach to understand is why we have to declare con as field and not log, when both of them are result of a function calling... Anyway, I would ask you all if you think this kind of situations are more or less pythonic than traditional mode.. .Thank you!!

Comment: There's no problem calling `getLogger` when we create `A`, we just can't call `get_conf('A', 'a_value')` because `A` hasn't finished being created yet.  This is just a way of delaying that call until after `A` has been created.

Answer (score 0):

`A` is not being initialized upon importing, but all those A' class variables are assigned then and so the right side of assignment like `ConfigParser.get_conf('A', 'a_value')` is executed.

If you make those variables instance level variables (by putting their declaration in `__init__`), they will be assigned upon calling that `a = A()`.

Comment: So there is a big difference between dataclasses and 'traditional' classes in the way the first ones do not replace the second ones.

I mean, in this case dataclass cannot save initalization code because it is mandatory to make instance level variables...

Comment: no, the problem here is just a failed name lookup that has nothing to do with classes at all. Just import your ConfigParser in the file where you declare the dataclass and you're fine.

Comment: I understand. The point here is that if ConfigParser has to be used in a whole project (multiple modules), is reasonable to intialize it at first as a classmethod to be always available to the rest of modules. What is unsense is to call it everytime in every module, isnt it?

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem. Why make it available in a class function? You just need to add `from config.config_parser import ConfigParser` to the file where you declare the dataclass to make everything work, don't you?

Comment: No, its what I am doing from the beginning (forgot to put in the code, it is edited already) and I get the error configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'FILES' cause it seems the dataclass is being loaded first through the imports...